# function dataTaskWithRequest in viewDidLoad doesn't affect variable

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsurlrequest

I would like to populate an `UITableViewController` so in my `viewDidLoad` I've this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let rc = RestCaller()
    rc.get( "events" , authenticate: true) {
        error, data in

        if error != nil {
            print("error")
        }

        let events = JSON( data: data )
        self.events = events["data"].arrayValue
    }

}
```

and there is my get function:

```
func get( route: String, authenticate: Bool?, next: (error: NSError?, data: NSData) -> Void )
{
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest( URL: NSURL( string: self.baseUrl + route )! )

    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    if authenticate != nil {
        request.addValue( getUserProperty( "USER_TOKEN" ) as! String, forHTTPHeaderField: "usertoken")
        request.addValue( (getUserProperty( "USER_ID" )?.stringValue)!, forHTTPHeaderField: "userid" )
    }

    _ = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest( request ) {
        data, response, error in

        next(error: error, data: data!)

    }.resume()
}
```

But in the `numberOfRowsInSection` method:

```
return events.count // return 0
```

But if I print self.events here:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...

        let events = JSON( data: data )
        self.events = events["data"].arrayValue
        print(self.events) // not empty 

    ...

}
```

And I don't understand why :(

Any idea ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It seem you forgot reload the table.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
let rc = RestCaller()
rc.get( "events" , authenticate: true) {
    error, data in

    if error != nil {
        print("error")
    }

    let events = JSON( data: data )
    self.events = events["data"].arrayValue

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```